# Configuring SSL to work with IIS and parse server

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, parse-server

I have an ssl certificate(Geotrust) installed to IIS 8, listening on port 443 and running on windows server 2012-r2. This works when I access https://myapp.example.com and it shows me the standard IIS page. My problem is that I am trying to connect to the parse-server(nodejs, express) running on serverUrl: http://localhost:1337/parse. So when trying to connect to https://myapp.example.com:1337/parse 
chrome says: "myapp.example.com finished the connection unexpectedly" and I cant reach the expected site.
ios-simulator says: kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806.

The connections to http works as expected on the urls described above.

I have tried to set the SSL port to 1337(and portforward 443->1337 on my router), but then I can not start the parse-server on the same port.

First time doing this, so really gratefull if anyone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing an reverse proxy in IIS 8.

I needed two applications in IIS and downloaded them like this: yourSite->right-click middle pane->"install application from gallery" and search & download these:

- Download URL Rewrite (i downloaded 3.0)
- Application Request Routing

This helped a lot:
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis